# arrays of structures and file I/O

Tags: c++

```
//i have two errors in my code
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
struct PLAYER
{
  string first_name;
 string last_name;
};
void showFile(fstream&, PLAYER&); // line 13
int main()
{
    const int MAX=21;
    PLAYER array[MAX];
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("PlayerNames.txt",ios::in);
    if(inputFile)
    {
        showFile(inputFile, array);  // line 22

    }else
        cout<<"\n\nError opening file";

    inputFile.close();
    return 0;
}
void showFile(fstream &file, PLAYER &array )
{
    int index=0;
    int p_num=1;
    string lname, fname;
    file>>lname>>fname;
    while(!file.eof())
    {

       // array[index].last_name=
       cout<<lname<<" "<<fname;
        //array[index].first_name=fname;
        //array[index].player_number=p_num;

        index++;
        p_num++;
        file>>lname>>fname;
    }
       // cout<<"\n"<<index;
        //cout<<lname<<" "<<fname;
}
```

This program worked finally untill i put it in functions.
I have two errors in this program
           line 22 error: invalid intialization of reference type std:: fstream
line 13 error: in passing argument 1 of void showFile(std:: fstream&, PLAYER&)

Comment: I assume this is C++?

Comment: yes, sorry i forgot to mention that

Comment: Your line 13 should be `void showFile(fstream &file, PLAYER &array )`

Comment: since thats my function prototype, i didn't add that.But I do have it in my function definition

Comment: trying adding `const` for `fstream` in the function...

Comment: An `ifstream` can't be converted to an `fstream`, only an `istream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ifstream` can't be converted to an `fstream`, only an `istream`.

In [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) you can see `basic_ifstream` is derived from `basic_istream`, not `basic_fstream`.

Make your function:

```
void showFile(istream&, PLAYER&);
```

This is actually better in many ways. For one it's correct (c: But also it means you can test it with any input stream rather than just a file stream. It is more loosely coupled and programs to the more abstract interface.

Comment: One more question, I am still having trouble passing my array of struct to my function. Any suggestions ? thank you for your time.

Comment: @alazargebeyehu You're probably best spending time working out a simple example of what's not working, and if it still doesn't work, look to see whether someone has asked something similar. Otherwise, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You function declaration at line 13 shows you are passing 1 `PLAYER` object, not an array.  If you want to stay with arrays, search StackOverflow for "[C++] pass array function".

I highly recommend using `std::vector` as it has easier syntax when passing to functions.